# Laravel 5.2 - MultiUpload inputs

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

i would like that my users can upload 4 images, this is the first time that i do a similar feature, but i don't know HOW DO IT? CREATE ARRAY? i would like have more inputs, i don't want use multiselect files, i'm tryng like this:

FORM HTML:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'crea-regalo','method'=>'POST','class' => 'form-horizontal', 'files'=>true)) !!}

<!-- photo -->
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="textarea"> Picture </label>
   <div class="col-md-8">

    <div class="mb10">

     <input id="input-upload-img1" name="image" type="file" class="file" data-preview-file-type="text">
   </div>

   <div class="mb10">

     <input id="input-upload-img2" name="image" type="file" class="file" data-preview-file-type="text">
   </div>


   <div class="mb10">

     <input id="input-upload-img3" name="image" type="file" class="file" data-preview-file-type="text">
   </div>


   <div class="mb10">

     <input id="input-upload-img4" name="image" type="file" class="file" data-preview-file-type="text">
   </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

CONTROLLER - Actually i have a code for only one image - It work well

```
public function creaPost(Request $request){
         // get id of post created by user
         $get_post_created = Post::where('slug', str_slug($request->input('title'),'-'))->first();
         // set file uploaded
         $file = $request->file('image');
         // create instance image intervation
         $image = image::make($request->file('image'));
         // create path
         $path = public_path().'/images/post/';
         // rename image with id user - if more one i can change this myself
         $name_file = $get_post_created->id . '.' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

        //resize
        $image->resize(100,100);
        // save image
        $image->save($path.$name_file);
        // update post with image uploaded
        $user = new Post;
        $user->where('id', '=', $get_post_created->id)->update(['image' => 'images/post/'.$name_file]);
        return redirect('/')->with('message-success', 'Post creato con successo!');
}
```

Comment: If you're uploading multiple files with the same input name, does specifying it as an array (`name="image[]"`) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `[]` to the name of the input:

```
<input id="input-upload-img1" name="image[]" type="file" class="file" data-preview-file-type="text">
```

Or:

```
{!! Form::file('image[]') !!}
```

You may also, remove 4 inputs and add this one, so user could choose 4 images in one file browser window:

```
{!! Form::file('image[]', ['multiple' => true]) !!}
```

In controller just iterate over an array to get each file:

```
foreach ($request->image as $image)
```

Comment: `<input id="input-upload-img1" name="image[]" type="file" class="file" data-preview-file-type="text" multiple>` add `multiple` attribute inside this input filed.

Comment: return $request->image; give me a value like this: [{},null,null,null] i tryed to upload only one image, and doesn't get the value